# Solidity with React

Tags: reactjs, installation, blockchain, ethereum, verify

I'm trying to make a Student Management System in Blockchain using Ethereum. I'm using Solidity for smart contract and trying to link it with React for the frontend. As of now, I'm getting the certificates, transcripts from the user.

But, I'm not knowing how to get the text input such as names, Department, phone number, house address from the user in React front end and store it in the smart contract, and also view the entered details.

Please help me with the code!

It will be really helpful if someone can give the code itself!!

Comment: hey welcome to stack. this question is pretty broad. have you tried anything yet? are you following the solidity / web3 documentation to figure out how to interact with your smart contract?

Comment: yeah, I'm using solidity and IPFS infura to interact with the smart contract. I know how to get files but I'm not sure of getting text values.  While on solidity I've written a code to the get the value from user.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is directly asking for working code